# algorithm to scale an image to best fit a frame (div)

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I am very weak in Math. I am a web programmer, and usually my work does not involve too much math - its more of putting records into database, pulling out reports, making those fancy web pages etc etc. So, I got a task that is "mathy" for me, but I am hoping its child's play for some of you Math guys out there, and you will help me out...It might even be an interesting problem for you, its just too complex for me.

So recently I got this task, where I am given an image with an area marked on top of it. This area would be marked as top left pixels (x1,y1) and bottom right pixels (x2,y2)
So for the image I have the following information:

```
Image Width (iw)
Image Height (ih)
Image Area Top Left (x1,y1)
Image Area Bottom Right (x2,y2)
```

Now there are a collection of frames, each frame will have `Frame Width (fw)` and `Frame Height (fh)`. My job is to find optimal way to fit Image Area inside frame without having any blank area inside frame, using image scaling if required.

So I broke it down to following tasks:

1. Image Area (not fill image) has to fit inside Frame. If `Image Area > Frame`, I should scale Image down (to a %). If `Image Area < Frame` I should scale Image Up.
2. The aspect ratio of the image should not be disturbed when I scale.
3. I should scale Image based on the longer side of Image Area to make sure that whole Image Area comes inside Frame. However when scaling Image down, sometimes this may cause the other side to have blank space inside Frame because of extreme aspect ratios. In such case, I should only scale down until one side hits Image Height or Image Width. This means that the Image Area is not fully shown inside the Frame, but that is fine because the first priority is to not have blank space inside Frame.

Now that I have written all these rules, I am unable to wrap my head around formalizing this into a mathematical "formula"/"procedure"/"rule-set" that I can then recreate in my software.

For scaling, I found that this formula works well (in programming pseudo-code):

```
imageX = Image.width()
imageY = Image.height();
imageRatio = imageX / imageY;

frameX = Frame.width();
frameY = Frame.height();
frameRatio = frameX / frameY;

if (imageRatio < wellRatio) 
{
    scale = imageX / wellX;
} 
else 
{
    scale = imageY / wellY;
}
resizeX = (imageX / scale);
resizeY = (imageY / scale);
```

However I do not know how to tie this into the whole picture.

Can anyone help me please? I have been trying unsuccessfully for over a week now :( I am using PHP and Javascript and I am pretty well versed with these two technologies. Usually I can solve most problems that I encounter day-to-day which involves them, however this is way over my head.

Comment: You're not allowed to use css for this?

Comment: @KjellIvar - no because technically, I need to pass the recalculated x1,y1 and x2,y2 along with scale factor to another API

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the priority is to fill the frame first so you don't have letterboxing for any image.

The best way to do this is to look for the shorter side and use CSS to stretch that side to fill the frame.  This will preserve the aspect ratio, but might cut off part of the image.

```
$('img').css(this.width > this.height ? 'height' : 'width', '100%');
```